# How to change title of a dragged mkannotationview

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to change the title of a mkannotationview when I drag it. MKannotationview doesn't have title property - i have a custom view for it. So how do I access it in the dragstate delegate method?

```
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
  didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:
  (MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
   {
   NSLog(@"old state, new state:%d, %d",oldState,newState);
   //view setTitle
   }
```

If i can call the viewforannotationdelegate method from here, that can help. So is that atleast possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct casting :

```
             ParkPlaceMark *annotation = (ParkPlaceMark *)view.annotation;
```

Placemark - My custom class;
view - mkannotationview

Comment: @bbodayle : Thanx for giving the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast the `MKAnnotationView`to your own subclass which contains your title property.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {

    if([view isKindOfClass:[CustomMKAnnotationView class]]) {
        CustomMKAnnotation *customView = (CustomMKAnnotation *)view.annotation;
        customView.title = @"New Title";

    }
}
```

Comment: The control is never going inside the loop :
 

       -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:   
       (MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:   
       (MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:
       (MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
       {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[ParkPlaceMark class]]) {
            ParkPlaceMark *customView = (ParkPlaceMark *)view;
            customView.title = @"POI";
          }
        }

Comment: - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map
            viewForAnnotation:(ParkPlaceMark*)annotation {
           MKAnnotationView *test=[[MKAnnotationView alloc]     
           initWithAnnotation:annotation 
           reuseIdentifier:@"parkingloc"];
    if([annotation.title caseInsensitiveCompare:@"POI"] ==  
           NSOrderedSame)
 {
        test.annotation = annotation;
        test.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        test.draggable = YES;
       [annotation setTitle:@"new title"];
        [test setEnabled:YES];
        [test setCanShowCallout:YES];
 }

Comment: I got an idea from your solution - but you ll have to complete it -

                ParkPlaceMark *park = [[ParkPlaceMark alloc] 
            initWithAnnotation:view reuseIdentifier:@"parkingloc"];

How do i init park's main object itself to mkannotationview?
Something like the already existing one :
In parkplacemark.h :
          @interface ParkPlaceMark : NSObject<MKAnnotation> 
          {....
           }

in placemark.m :

     - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate: 
      (CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
 [super init];
 title = ttl;
 coordinate = c2d;
 return self;
       }